# Exclude resource from dependency in gradle android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-proguard

I have a gradle android project.
I've set **minifyEnabled true** in my build.gradle

I want to exclude some resource files from dependencies. It's for example gwt.xml files and logging configuration files.

proguard copy all resource files by default. So, if I use proguard directly, I can write

> -injars  in.jar(!**/*.gwt.xml)

**But how can I do it with gradle android plugin?**

---

P.s. I know about

> packagingOptions { 
>   exclude 'Proj.gwt.xml'
>   }

It looks working with one file per **exclude**
It's pretty unusable to list all files here.